# Product secondary picture linked to the product option on Big Cartel / Luna Template

Tags: bigcartel

I am wondering whether there is on option to display secondary picture when relevant option is chosen.

For the reference this is the product: https://www.evascentemporium.com/product/black-coconut-scented-wax-melts

I would like second image to show when second option is selected.

Thank you in advance.

Asia